# server crashes with 5 concurrent users for a page, when should support thousands

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, python, django

Whats happening is we have a data heavy view that has maybe 10 ajax calls, some of which are long running. During a load test for this specific page, with around 5-10 concurrent users the whole server will go down, even on a huge server (64 CPUs).

the stack is Django, Gunicorn, Docker, Nginx, Ubuntu.

Protocol is HTTP 1.1, Nginx keepalive is on. The timeout is 65 seconds.

During load testing for any other page, the site can run 1000s of users without even much impact on CPU.

The only metric that is peaking when it crashes is bandwidth, everything else is still very low.

I asked around on IRC and most communities were stumped as to what was going on, aside from things I'd already investigated.

I have a bunch of suspicions I'm testing at the moment, but I'd love to hear from someone who has seen something similar, as I haven't.

I realize that there are application level ways to mitigate a high runtime load, for reasons I can't really get into this avenue has been exhausted. I'm just trying to understand if I have a configuration problem or its totally an application design problem and I need to send people back to the drawing board.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share some of those metrics with us and also talk more about what is it doing/using, especially if there's some heavy DB operation going on?

Comment: Your description of your stack is missing details; where is Django's database? Where is the data on this 'data-heavy' page? Perhaps you should be Celery or similar for divorcing request from response and making your pages more asynchronous.

Comment: You need to be quite familiar with the limitations around gunicorn and the architecture of your application. Read carefully the documentation in http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html and http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html. Check also that for any cycles that may be formed in the critical data path of the request.